# Why is my bar graph in ggplot looking strange in ggbarplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Here is my data for December:

```
structure(list(case = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 
49L), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), month = c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L), type1 = c("drink", 
"food", "laundry", "laundry", "drink", "alcohol", "food", "alcohol", 
"food", "drink", "food", "food", "food", "alcohol", "food", "food", 
"food", "alcohol", "drink", "drink", "food", "drink", "travel", 
"travel", "food", "drink", "food", "travel", "travel", "drink", 
"food", "drink", "food", "travel", "food", "travel", "travel", 
"travel", "food", "drink", "misc", "misc", "misc", "misc", "food", 
"food", "food", "food", "misc", "misc", "food", "food", "food", 
"alcohol", "alcohol", "food", "wifi", "electric", "rent", "food", 
"food", "drink", "drink", "drink", "food", "food", "misc", "drink", 
"drink", "misc", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", 
"drink", "food", "travel", "alcohol", "food", "drink", "food", 
"food", "food", "travel", "laundry", "laundry", "alcohol", "food", 
"food", "food", "drink", "food", "drink", "travel", "travel", 
"food", "food", "alcohol", "food", "drink", "food", "misc", "food", 
"drink", "alcohol", "food", "travel", "travel", "travel", "drink", 
"travel", "drink", "food", "alcohol", "travel", "drink", "travel", 
"drink", "food", "misc", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", 
"food", "alcohol", "food", "drink", "alcohol", "food", "travel", 
"food", "alcohol", "food", "alcohol", "travel", "travel", "food", 
"food", "drink", "food", "misc", "misc", "food", "misc", "alcohol", 
"food", "food", "food", "drink", "misc", "travel", "drink", "food", 
"drink", "food", "alcohol", "food", "food", "alcohol", "food", 
"drink", "misc", "food", "alcohol", "food", "travel", "laundry", 
"food", "drink", "misc", "laundry", "food", "food", "drink", 
"food", "food", "travel", "drink", "alcohol", "alcohol", "food", 
"food", "alcohol", "food", "food", "food", "misc", "misc", "misc", 
"misc", "food", "drink", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", 
"food", "alcohol", "food"), amount = c(9.5, 7, 14, 24, 13, 32, 
20, 29, 23.9, 21, 73.8, 16.9, 53.8, 12.9, 17, 16.9, 8.5, 35, 
49, 12, 26, 18, 10, 8, 41, 11, 12, 10, 8, 8, 18, 18, 10, 20, 
378, 8, 5, 6, 109, 14, 46, 14.9, 8, 29.9, 10.5, 19.9, 12.9, 36.8, 
21.9, 24.9, 10, 7, 8, 35, 24, 20, 436, 99, 7300, 26.9, 45.9, 
13.9, 11.9, 9.9, 12, 9.9, 0.5, 12.9, 90, 33, 15.5, 24, 40, 12, 
10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12.9, 10.5, 27.9, 13.5, 24.9, 19.9, 8, 28, 
24, 42.8, 19, 48, 21, 52, 7.5, 18.5, 5, 4, 100, 32.9, 29.8, 26, 
8.5, 10, 300, 53, 13, 223, 14, 11, 8, 5.7, 20, 40, 14, 20, 27, 
5.7, 20, 17.8, 70, 170, 39.9, 27, 20, 22, 24, 10.5, 20, 26, 31, 
20, 26.4, 37.5, 18.1, 190, 25.9, 100, 26, 8, 11, 41, 16, 18, 
14, 28, 13, 10.5, 59, 8, 18.9, 73.8, 7.5, 52, 0.5, 11.2, 18.5, 
75, 28, 15, 24, 10, 16.9, 20.2, 73, 18, 14.5, 10, 35, 37, 5.6, 
15, 37, 17.5, 143, 24, 27, 12, 9.5, 12, 41, 5.6, 38, 44, 60, 
14.5, 34, 30, 19.9, 33.9, 24.3, 60, 12, 12, 35, 12, 52, 15, 10.5, 
8.5, 13, 49.5, 27, 31.9, 17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-204L))
```

I usually have a pretty seamless transition from ggplot to ggpubr, but today I'm having an issue with the bar graph function. When I make this pretty simple bar in ggplot:

```
budget %>% 
  filter(month==12) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=type1,
         weight = amount,
         fill = type1))+
  geom_bar()+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Bar Graph : Spending by Type for December",
       x="Type of Spending",
       y="Amount (HKD)")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I get this normal bar:

[image]

However when I try to do the same in ggbarplot:

```
budget %>% 
  filter(month==12) %>% 
  ggbarplot(x="type1",
         y="amount",
         fill = "type1")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Bar Graph : Spending by Type for December",
       x="Type of Spending",
       y="Amount (HKD)")
```

I get this weird bar graph that facets by each amount spent:

[image]

Tried reviewing the ggbarplot help page in R, but I can't seem to really pick out which argument I'm missing to fix this or if its just my own filtering error I need to fix.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the plot using your code. The data contains only month 11.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because you have a `y` in the function `ggbarplot()` and you used `weight` in `ggplot()`. They are not equivalent.

Comment: Yeah I know they're different but I don't know if there is a `weight` argument for ggbarplot. I only know that it has to have a `y` argument, which I assume is the best equivalent to `weight`.

Comment: Please add the data for the 12th month. I am unable to reproduce the issue with the given data.

Comment: I've edited it to include just December

Comment: There's an error in your data. Not able to create `budget` dataframe.

Comment: Why do you want to use 'ggpubr' adding one additional layer of code, which can be a source of trouble, when the code using 'ggplot2' is simple enough? Is it just to avoid using `aes()`? (You can use package 'reprex' to create an example that is consistent with the output.)

Comment: Most of the time I find it requires a lot simpler coding compared to ggplot, its more easily customizable, and it can be directly ported into things like the plotly package for interactive plots.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have been trying to understand why 'ggpubr' is so popular. Your answer makes sense. (I have been using 'ggplot2' for so long that I do not find it difficult to code with it...)

Comment: I dont find either difficult to code and in fact there is a lot of similarity between the two. I think its more a preference thing than anything. You still have to add ggplot code to ggpubr plots if you wanna customize it more, so its still essential to be good at both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggbarplot` drew a bar for every record with a black outline so you need to `filter` the `month == 12` then `group_by` the `type1` and `summarize` the amount before calling `ggbarplot` then it will work fine.

```r
# I recognize that in your example type1 data is not factorized
# Which results different color code on different graph. adjusted a bit now
budget$type1 <- factor(budget$type1)

budget %>%
  filter(month==12) %>% 
  group_by(type1) %>%
  summarize(amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  ggbarplot(x="type1",
            y="amount",
            fill = "type1") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Bar Graph : Spending by Type for December",
       x="Type of Spending",
       y="Amount (HKD)")
```

[image]

Or you specifying the color aesthetic as well so that the outline is the same color with the fill.

```r
budget %>% 
  filter(month==12) %>% 
  ggbarplot(x="type1",
            y="amount",
            fill = "type1",
            color = "type1") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Bar Graph : Spending by Type for December",
       x="Type of Spending",
       y="Amount (HKD)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>